# How do I get my HTML form date input to only allow specific days of the week to be chosen using JavaScript, React and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, date, calendar

I am trying to get my Forms Date Input to only allow Thursday, Friday, and Saturday to be selected. But I can't seem to find a way to do it.

Is there some JavaScript or HTML code I could use to solve this issue?

Here is my current code

```
import React from 'react';

const CustomForm = () => {

const addTwoWeeks = function () {

        let today = new Date();
        today.setDate(today.getDate() + 14);

        let dd = today.getDate();
        let mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
        let yyyy = today.getFullYear();

        if (dd < 10) {
            dd = '0' + dd
        }
        if (mm < 10) {
            mm = '0' + mm
        }

        today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

        return today;
    }
 

return (

<form>

<label htmlFor="date">Pick-Up Date:</label>
<input type="date" id="date" name="date" min={addTwoWeeks()} required />

</form>

)
}

export default CustomForm;
```

Comment: I don't think you can disable specific weekdays (e.g showing it in a disabled state) from the HTML5 selector itself. You'll need a third-party date picker plugin.
The only restrictions you can put on the HTML5 input datepicker are its lower and upper bounds through the min and max attributes.

Comment: This one is quite simple to set up https://reactdatepicker.com/

Comment: You can just have a validator rule and check wether the day is a specific weekday or not and only allow the form to submit if it's an accepted value else add an error message regarding this restriction to inform the users. Why don't you do something like this? If you want to stick with the native datepicker, then there is no other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple if you will use datepicker js

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      beforeShowDay: function (d) {
         var day = d.getDay();
         return [day != 0 && day != 1 && day != 2 && day != 3];
     },
});
```

[image]

Full working example:

```html
<html>
        <head>
            <title>HTML</title>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" ></script>
            <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                    beforeShowDay: function (d) {
                        var day = d.getDay();
                        return [day != 0 && day != 1 && day != 2 && day != 3];
                    },
                });
            });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<input type="date" />` does not allow disabling specific days of the week. See [here (MDN docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#additional_attributes).

In that case, you can either

1. Prevent form submission and showing a proper validation message for the invalid day selection.
2. Or, use a third-party react date picker/calendar library (or, if you have time, implement a datepicker).

I recommend [react-dates(Github link)](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates) in case you go for option 2. Keep in mind the size of the import though.

```
<SingleDatePickerWrapper isDayBlocked={isDayBlocked} autoFocus />
```

[Here(Storybook)](http://airbnb.io/react-dates/?path=/story/sdp-day-props--blocks-fridays) is a variant/example which blocks day selection for Fridays. Link to the corresponding [code(Gtihub)](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/blob/6c2cb61c5e876fbdac72e6efed49c0bd64f06d6b/stories/SingleDatePicker_day.js#L55) .